# Update Field Based on another Field in Json Schema

Tags: jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

How to update a field based on the changes in another field in React Json Schema? Below is my schema object.

To simplify the use case, let's say I have a Countries dropdown field set to Canada by default and Currency text field that is empty. If there is a change in Countries, currency text field should display SGD.

```
{
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        country: {
            title: 'Country',
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['Canada', 'Singapore', ..., 'United States'],
            default: 'Canada',
        },
        currency: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
    },
    dependencies: {
        country: {
            properties: {
                currency: {
                    const: 'SG',
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode, "if the property countries exists and its value is Canada then currency is CAD; if the property countries exists and its value is SG..."

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else

So therefore:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "countries", "currency" ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "countries": { "const": "Canada" } },
      "else": { "properties": { "currency": { "const": "CAD" } } },
    },
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "countries": { "const": "Singapore" } },
      "else": { "properties": { "currency": { "const": "SG" } } },
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```